# Qual a diferença entre usar focusin/focusout e focus/blur?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Utilizando jQuery para focar um elemento específico surgiu a dúvida:

Qual a diferença entre usar **`focusin()`** em relação à **`focus()`**?

E **`focusout()`** em relação ao **`blur()`**?

Há alguma aplicação específica para cada caso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resumidamente,

`.focusin()` e `.focusout()` são eventos que "borbulham", enquanto `.focus()` e `.blur()` não.

Executando o exemplo abaixo você notará que o `input` chama todos os eventos, o `parent` apenas o `focusin` e `focusout`.

obs* "Borbulhamento" é o conceito que define a propagação de um evento para diferentes níveis da hierarquia DOM.

```js
function log(str){
  $('.log').append($('<div/>').text(str));
}

$('.parent')
    .focusin(function(){log('div focusin');})
    .focusout(function(){log('div focusout');})
    .focus(function(){log('div focus');})
    .blur(function(){log('div blur');});
$('input')
    .focusin(function(){log('input focusin');})
    .focusout(function(){log('input focusout');})
    .focus(function(){log('input focus');})
    .blur(function(){log('input blur');});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="log"></div>
```

Fonte Snippet: [diff between focus focusin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858979/difference-between-focusin-focusout-and-focus-blur-with-example)

Comment: Gostaria de saber também se há algum caso específico ou um exemplo de quando utilizar um ou outro? Obrigado!

Comment: @ℛɑƒæĿ Da uma olhada nesse fiddle que criei, tem os comentários com as explicações, qualquer dúvida comenta ai. https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/3uL8aoeh/2/